# open a pdf using adobe air on android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, pdf, air, adobe

Hi I'm trying to open a pdf from air on an android device, I'm using Flash CC to author it.  The code I have works in the Air debug launcher but fails on the device. The PDF is included in the APK. Am I addressing the PDF correctly? Does

```
openWithDefaultApplication();
```

work on android?

```
import flash.filesystem.*;

var thePDF = "poppinchicken.pdf";
var realFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(thePDF);
var destination:File = File.cacheDirectory;
destination = destination.resolvePath(thePDF);
realFile.copyTo(destination,true);


But01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, outputbox7zz);
function outputbox7zz(e: MouseEvent): void {



destination.openWithDefaultApplication();
}
```

Comment: This question fails to show basic research of the problem. Typing `does openWithDefaultApplication work on android` yields the correct answer on first result. Answer on adobe forums [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3864346)

Comment: CyanAngel is right. User, I recommend you read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help and get acquainted with what is expected of you when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Because the PDFs are hosted on the web I'm able to solve this simply for this project using

```
var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.hotnkickin.co.uk/mansion/pdf/chickenfillets.pdf");
navigateToURL(request);
```

This hasn't solved my original question but the result works for me in this instance, and so might help another new starter like me.